# Why is IList not deferred execution?

Tags: c#, collections

As I understand it IEnumerable and IQueryable are deferred execution. Why wouldn't it be of benefit for IList to also support deferred execution?

Comment: What if you don't want deferred execution, what would you use if you couldn't use a List?

Comment: What do you mean by "are deferred execution"? A method implementation can be deferred, but IEnumerable, IQueryable and IList are interfaces. The questions doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The longer I think about it, the more I question whether the whole idea of "deferred execution" is actually of pedagogic value at all.

I'll answer your question by denying it. `IEnumerable<T>`, `IQueryable<T>` and `IList<T>` do not in any way represent "deferred" or "eager" calculations.

Rather, **interfaces represent an ability to provide a service**.  `IEnumerable<T>` represents the service "I can provide a sequence, possibly infinite, of items of type T, one at a time".  `IQueryable<T>` represents the service "I can represent a query against a data source, and provide the results of that query on demand".  `IList<T>` represents the service "I can provide random access to a possibly mutable, finite-sized list of items of type T".

None of those services say anything about the implementation details of the service providers. The provider of an `IList<T>` service could be entirely lazy; the provider of an `IQueryable<T>` service could be entirely eager. If you want to make a deferred-execution `IList<T>`, you go right ahead. No one is stopping you!

Comment: I think the idea of deferred execution is of pedagogic value, but it ought to be better defined - indeed, I've argued before that "lazy" is a hideously vague term, used all over the place in subtly different ways. (http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/03/25/just-how-lazy-are-you.aspx) What remains unclear to me is how much it's useful for (say) LINQ to Objects to rigidly define how its uses its inputs and at what points. (Some of the existing documentation is plain wrong - such as Intersect - but that's a different matter.)

Comment: But there is some expectation or assumption (even if it is implied or by convention) that `IQueryable` with be deferred and `IEnumerable` will be eager, no?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I expect that IQueryable will represent *a query* and that every time the query is executed, the most up-to-date result will be fetched. That does not *necessarily* imply a lazy implementation. The IQueryable implementation might eagerly fetch records from the back-end store and then invalidate its cache later when necessary.  It's up to the implementor.

Answer (score 21):

`IList<T>` supports random access via the indexer - as well as the `Count` property. Both of these go against the spirit of deferred execution with streaming data, unless you're suggesting that you *really* just want something which loads the entire list as soon as you access *anything*. If that's what you're after, `Lazy<T>` might be the ticket...

Comment: Well it could well be that it is not complicated to get the number of elements, but is is complicated to get the value of each element (or even dynamic values). So a lazy evaluted IList makes sense. Assume we have something that somehow returns the pressure of each wheel of a vehicle. It would be easy to get the number of wheels of the bike/car/lorry/... but the values are a different story...

Comment: @EskeRahn: There can be many different cases where *some* aspects can be lazy and some not. But describing that in a useful way in an interface list `IList<T>` ends up being tricky. There's nothing to *stop* you from implementing `IList<T>` in a lazy way, but it doesn't inherently *lend* itself to laziness.

Comment: Sure. As humans we intuitively think of an IList as a dynamic though deterministic array, but that is a narrower definition than is required by the interface, and my point is that we tend to forget that,

Answer (score 8):

As @Joe pointed out, `IList<T>` abstracts a *noun*. `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` are abstractions of *verbs*.

`IList<T>` is an abstraction of a collection that can be treated as a list. `IEnumerable<T>` and 'IQueryable abstract actions: the enumeration over, or querying of the items contained in the underlying collection.

Answer (score 3):

Think through the consequences of what you're saying.

What would be deferred, and until when?

In the case of `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` what's deferred is the enumeration.  And the interfaces don't expose anything else that depends on the enumeration having been done.

Answer (score 2):

There are a multitude of reasons, just some:

- an `IList` should be *independent* from the underlying data source that
  was used to create the `IList`
- accessing an `IList` member by index is expected to be O(1) - with deferred execution this cannot be guaranteed - access might be very slow, at least the first time.
- accessing an `IList` member should not produce an exception because of how the `IList` being constructed when you access (there are all sorts of problems that can arise with deferred execution, think i.e. not being able to access the original data source) - this is going back to the first point.

Comment: You could go even further as an IList might not need to actually produce the values to know the count, and only actually produce specific values on request.